# Delphi IcmpPing Exception only in release, ok in debug

Tags: delphi

The following code is a test of the IcmpPing routine called from the icmp dll.  In debug it works fine but in release it throws an error.  The error is caused by the "IcmpCloseHandle" call  because calling IcmpSendEcho has somehow changed the handle.  It has the feel of a memory problem but so far the only fix I have found it to take a copy of the handle and use that for the close handle call.  I have trimmed the code to down to minimum including having the ip address as an integer (127.0.0.1 = $0100007F little endian). What am I doing wrong?  I have tested this problem on 2010, XE2 and XE4 all with the same problem.

Any ideas

---

```
unit icmptest1;

interface

uses
//  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
//  Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TSunB = packed record
    s_b1, s_b2, s_b3, s_b4: byte;
  end;

  TSunW = packed record
    s_w1, s_w2: word;
  end;

  PIPAddr = ^TIPAddr;
  TIPAddr = record
    case integer of
      0: (S_un_b: TSunB);
      1: (S_un_w: TSunW);
      2: (S_addr: longword);
  end;

 IPAddr = TIPAddr;

  PICMP_ECHO_REPLY = ^ICMP_ECHO_REPLY;
  ICMP_ECHO_REPLY = packed record
    Address : IPAddr;
    Status : ULONG;
    RoundTripTime : ULONG;
    DataSize : WORD;
    Reserved : WORD;
    Data : Pointer;
  end;

  PIP_OPTION_INFORMATION = ^IP_OPTION_INFORMATION;
  IP_OPTION_INFORMATION = packed record
    Ttl : byte;
    Tos : byte;
    Flags : byte;
    OptionsSize : byte;
    OptionsData : Pointer;
  end;

type
  TForm34 = class(TForm)
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

function  IcmpCreateFile : HWnd; stdcall; external 'icmp.dll';
function  IcmpCloseHandle(const IcmpHandle : HWnd) : longbool; stdcall; external 'icmp.dll';
function  IcmpSendEcho(const IcmpHandle: HWnd; const DestinationAddress: IPAddr ;const RequestData: Pointer;const RequestSize : WORD;const RequestOptions : PIP_OPTION_INFORMATION;const ReplyBuffer : Pointer;const ReplySize : DWORD;const TimeOut : DWORD) : DWORD; stdcall; external 'icmp.dll';

var
  Form34: TForm34;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{$T+}

function IcmpPing1(): Boolean;
var
  dwSize : DWORD;
  DW: DWord;
  IPAddr: TIPAddr;
  EchoReply: ICMP_ECHO_REPLY;
  hICMP : HWnd;
  Hc: HWnd;

begin
  Result := False;
  hICMP := IcmpCreateFile;
  Hc := hICMP;

  if hICMP <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    try
      dwSize := SizeOf(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + 8;

      IPAddr.S_addr := $0100007F; // 127.0.0.1

      ShowMessage(Format('1: %x',[hICMP]));
      DW := IcmpSendEcho(hICMP, IPAddr, nil, 0, nil, @EchoReply, dwSize, 500);
      hICMP := Hc;
      ShowMessage(Format('2: %x',[hICMP]));

      Result := (EchoReply.Status = 0);
    finally
      try
        IcmpCloseHandle(hICMP);
      except
        on e:exception do
          ShowMessage(e.Message);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm34.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Byte(IcmpPing1())));
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is that you have forgot to add options to the ICMP_ECHO_REPLY and therefor got the wrong size for the buffer

```
type
  PIP_OPTION_INFORMATION = ^IP_OPTION_INFORMATION;
  IP_OPTION_INFORMATION = packed record
    Ttl : byte;
    Tos : byte;
    Flags : byte;
    OptionsSize : byte;
    OptionsData : Pointer;
  end;



  PICMP_ECHO_REPLY = ^ICMP_ECHO_REPLY;
  ICMP_ECHO_REPLY = packed record
    Address : in_addr;
    Status : ULONG;
    RoundTripTime : ULONG;
    DataSize : WORD;
    Reserved : WORD;
    Data : Pointer;
    **options : IP_OPTION_INFORMATION;**
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**

The replybuffer is too small relative to the declared size "dwSize := SizeOf(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + 8".  I have added 8 bytes to the replybuffer to hold extra reply data.

The answer is to add the 8 bytes to the record and make dwSize := SizeOf(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY);.

Having dumped the replybuffer contents its obvious that the reply was overwriting other variables.